# Eclipse returns error on run: "java selection does not contain a main type"

Tags: java, eclipse-indigo

I am unable to run the following code in Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149), and I think that I may have a configuration problem in Eclipse (but I do not know what or where):

```
class Saluton {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String greeting = "Saluton mondo!";
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

I am also running against Java 6 (1.6.0_29-b11-402) on Macintosh 10.7.2.

When I run this, I get the error:

> "java selection does not contain a main type"

but I am pretty sure that my class is written correctly...? I have looked this error up, and cannot explain this problem so far.

TIA for any thoughts or opinions!

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: From the Run button in the eclipse tool bar. I have tried to run both as an application and an applet with the same failure both times.

Comment: If you look at the run config does it show the correct class etc.?

Comment: Hrm. I really do not know, but I will check into this. Thanks!

Comment: This is what my project looks like. I do not think that the project is marked to show that it has a main type:        http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5271440/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-08%20at%202.13.07%20PM.png

Comment: It needs to be in the source directory; that class won't even be compiled. Also, put it in a package.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make your class public, otherwise it won't work?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My previous answer was incorrect. The JLS says you can declare arrays with the brackets at either end. [See here for some examples](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.2). My mistake.

Have you verified your configuration in Eclipse such that it knows where to find the Java compiler, and a JVM? You can check the project-specific libraries by right clicking the project and going to **Properties**, **Java Build Path**

[image: java build path]

You can also check the JRE's installed by clicking **Window**, **Preferences**, **Java**, **Installed JREs**. Make sure the JRE you wish to use is listed here and that the path is correct.

[image]

Comment: No, it's not; they can go either place. Convention puts them on the type, but this is not required. [JLS 10.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.2)

Comment: I just checked that after I said it. There I go again shooting and then asking questions. I'll edit it appropriately.

Comment: The screenshot added by the OP pretty much sums it up. Plus the exception wouldn't show up if it wasn't *trying* to run and not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (simple and direct):

In Eclipse: *File -> Restart*

Answer (score 0):

**Right click** your class `Saluton`  and choose **Run as**  --> **Java Application**.

It should work.

Comment: When I did that, I got the following in the console:    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Your project setup is sooo messed up then. Get someone expert in eclipse who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I took the long way around to solve this; eventually I created a package within my project and added my source code to that package and it compiled and ran! I am learning that Wizards rule!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm a fellow noob, and I came here because I had this problem. I checked all my class paths and everything, and they were correct. I had actually been putting all of my files in the JRE System Library Folder, instead of the source folder. I'm not sure if this was you'r problem, but it seemed to work for me when I moved the code files into the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you make your class as public !

Comment: please don't invent words (like "u" or similar) - it makes your answer hard to read and looks unprofessional.