# Eclipse error when trying to run Java application - "Selection does not contain a main type" - But it does?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package, program-entry-point

I have created a Java package, Matrix. When I attempt to run it, I get the error "Selection does not contain a main type". But, as the code that I've copied and pasted from the class DriverMatrix shows, there is a main method declaration. I have attempted to restart Eclipse and I still get the error. I created the package called Matrix, then imported .java files for each class. Anyone know what's going on here? Here is the main declaration along with just a bit of code:

```
package Matrix;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverMatrix 
{

static private IntegerArithmetics integerArithmetics = new IntegerArithmetics();
static private DoubleArithmetics doubleArithmetics = new DoubleArithmetics();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("in.txt"));
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("out.txt");

    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix1 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,3);
    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix2 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,3);
    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix3 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,3);
    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix4 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,3);
    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix5 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,3,2);
    Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix6 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,2);
```

Comment: What is the full error stack? What line does it refer to in your code?

Comment: In eclipse you might try right-clicking your class and `Run as -> Java Application` but I haven't got eclipse to try this myself.

Comment: possible dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781663/eclipse-returns-error-on-run-java-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type?rq=1

Comment: Is it in a Java Project in a Source Folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a `Matrix` class and package name conflict in your project and it may be leading to eclipse error. Try renaming one of those and then run your application.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code

```
Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics> matrix1 = new Matrix<Integer,IntegerArithmetics>(integerArithmetics,2,3);
```

it seems that you have a package and class with both entitled as Matrix. Try to change this first as naming conflict will obviously cause error.

Source: [Naming a package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: Thank you! I've just started using Eclipse and am new to Java in general. I wasn't aware of the naming conventions for packages.